# How to create a stacked-100% bar chart in PowerBI with multiple binary variables bars on the same x-axis sharing a common count y-axis

Tags: bar-chart, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to build a stacked-100% bar chart in PowerBi that can include multiple binary variables on the x-axis and have the same y-axis variable (continuous count).This is the data:

|System | Active | Passive | Sentinel|
|-------|--------|---------|---------|
|ASPC   | Yes    | No      | Yes     |
|CRD    | No     | Yes     | No      |
|APD    | No     | No      | Yes     |
etc....

I've created a system_count measure which used the System variable with a simple count of the number of systems.  I'd like to create a staked-100% bar chart with the each of the Active, Passive and Sentinel variables plotted on the same bar chart with and sharing system y-axis variable (system_count), with count and percentage labels on the bar charts.

I've tried to create it but can only have 1 binary variable on the x-axis at at time. I can't figure out how to add multiple variables onto the x-axis.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Please help!